# How to fetch current month data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

How to fetch current month data from database. I tried the the following, Its fetch all data related to this month from all years. I mean November data of all previous years.

```
SELECT d.date,
       COALESCE(t1.marks, 0) AS class1,
       COALESCE(t2.marks, 0) AS class2, 
       COALESCE(t3.marks, 0) AS class3
FROM (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date FROM `table1`
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(date_column) FROM `table2`
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(date_column) FROM `table3`) AS d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table1
           GROUP BY date) t1 ON t1.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY date) t2 ON t2.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table3
           GROUP BY date) t3 ON t3.date = d.date
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(d.dates) ORDER BY d.date
```

Comment: just add another condition ...AND YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(d.dates)

Comment: @GeorgeDryser thank you it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Year filter in where clause as below

```
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(d.date) and YEAR(CURDATE())=YEAR(d.date) ORDER BY d.date
```

This will get the data on the current month as well as the current year.